# RBAC with Ory Keto and ownership of objects

Tags: authorization, rbac, ory

I'm trying to achieve the following points with Ory Keto:

1. `UserA` has ownership of `ProductA` -> Ownership gives one CRUD rights.
2. `UserB` has the role `Admin` -> `Admin` gives one CRUD rights on everything.
3. `UserA` has a role `KYCVerified` or is part of a group named `KYCVerified` -> This gives the user additional permissions.

Point 1 describes the concept of ownership, which is described as one of the shortcomings of RBAC ([source](https://www.ory.sh/docs/keto/guides/rbac)) with the current state of Ory Keto:

> There is no concept of ownership: Dan is the author of article "Hello
> World" and is thus allowed to update it.

Point 2 describes a role that basically passes the ownership check, since this role can do everything. This should be possible in the current state, but not in combination with point 1.

Point 3 describes basically the same thing as point 2, but this is more specific to my use case.

I've read [this](https://www.ory.sh/docs/keto/guides/rbac) article on the Ory website and [this](https://gruchalski.com/posts/2021-05-15-rbac-with-ory-keto/) article. However, I'm still unable to wrap my head around this concept. I've made the following example of how I see the concept of ownership with Ory Keto:

```
# Tenant TenantA needs to be a owner of product ProductA in order to view it
products:ProductA#view@(tenants:TenantA#owner)

# Tenant A is a owner of ProductA
tenants:ProductA#owner@TenantA
```

But this will result in a lot of rules and I'm not even sure if this is the way to go.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of this moment you are right. You have to create a bunch of tuples manually. The full set of tuples should be something like:

```
products:ProductA#owner@UserA
products:ProductA#crud@(products:ProductA#owner)
roles:admin#member@UserB
products:ProductA#crud@(roles:admin#member)
products:ProductA#additional_permissions@(roles:KYCVerified#member)
roles:KYCVerified#member@UserA
```

Since https://github.com/ory/keto/pull/877 you are now able to define global rewrites:

```js
import { Context, Namespace } from @ory/keto-config

/**
 * "User" is a namespace with no additional rewrite rules defined.
 */
class User implements Namespace {}

/**
 * "Role"s only have members.
 */
class Role implements Namespace {
  related: {
    members: User[]
  }
}

/**
 * "Product" is a namespace representing a product. It has some rewrites.
 */
class Product implements Namespace {
  // Relations are defined and type-annotated.
  related: {
    /**
     * "owners" are the users that are the owners of the product.
     */
    owners: User[]
    /**
     * "admins" are the roles that are administrators of this product (potentially only one).
     */
    admins: Role[]
    /**
     * "special_roles" are the roles a user has to be member of to gain "additional_permissions"
     */
    special_roles: Role[]
  }

  permits = {
    // this is probably three/four rewrites (create, read, update, delete) with similar rules
    crud: (ctx: Context): boolean =>
      this.related.owners.includes(ctx.subject) ||
      this.related.admins.traverse((admin) => admin.related.members.includes(ctx.subject)),

    // for the additional_permissions one has to have crud and be member of a special role
    additional_permissions: (ctx: Context): boolean =>
      this.permits.crud(ctx) &&
      this.related.special_roles.traverse((role) => role.related.members.includes(ctx.subject))
  }
}
```

With that you have to create these tuples:

```
products:ProductA#owners@UserA
roles:admin#members@UserB
roles:KYCVerified#members@UserA

products:ProductA#admins@(roles:admin)
products:ProductA#additional_permissions@(roles:KYCVerified)
```

Please note that it is not possible (and not planned right now) to define a single `admin` group that would have access to everything. You always have to have some kind of relation between the object and subject to query/rewrite it. That is the reason for having the `admins` and `special_roles` relations.

Comment: I believe the syntax now that #877 has landed is this.related.admins.traverse(a => a.related.members.includes(ctx.subject))